# How do I shake from current position?

Tags: css, animation

I am using this css animation to shake a element.

```
.shake {
  animation: shake 0.82s;
}

@keyframes shake {
  10%, 90% {
    transform: translate3d(-1px, 0, 0);
  }  
  20%, 80% {
    transform: translate3d(2px, 0, 0);
  }
  30%, 50%, 70% {
    transform: translate3d(-4px, 0, 0);
  }
  40%, 60% {
    transform: translate3d(4px, 0, 0);
  }
}
```

The animation always happens at the left side of the browser. How do I get the animation to work at the current position of the element I want to shake?

For example: If I want to shake a element that is located at the right side of the browser. The element first moves to the left and shakes, then moves to the right again. That is not what I want. I want the element to shake where it is located and not move to the left first.

Comment: In which axis you want to start ? do want to have shake animation from top to bottom?

Comment: No, from left to right.

Comment: you have move atleast  one side to create shaking animations. I think you want to animation from current position to right ,then right to current position I'm right ?

Comment: From current position yes, horizontally.

Comment: Your example did not solve my problem. Your example is pretty much the same as mine.

Comment: @PeterKarlsson I guess your code is working fine https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/fvq7u0pk/

Comment: could you please explain it clearly if you don't want to move from current position then can't shake .please clearly specify the starting and direction of animation.translate3d(tx, ty, tz)  where tx is the translation along the x-axis, ty is the translation along the y-axis, and tz is the translation along the z-axis.

Comment: Bhuwan, your example works, thanks. I know what the problem is now. The element I want to move is already moved with transform. Replace the float line in your example with transform: translate3d(100px,0,0); and you will see my problem. I want to shake the element from that position.

Comment: @PeterKarlsson in that case use `margin-left:100px` instead of `transform: translate3d(100px,0,0)`

Comment: Bhuwan, I can't do that because the element is slided to that position. Let me explain a little bit more what I am trying to do. The element I am talking about is a div that slides in from the right. Let's call the div a modal. Some inputs are located in the modal. If something goes wrong when the user clicks on the save button the modal should shake to tell the user that something is wrong. So I suppose I must know the position of the modal to be able to make it shake at the current position.

Comment: Amaresh S M, please read my explanation I wrote to Bhuwan. That explains more what I am trying to do.

Comment: @PeterKarlsson try this https://jsfiddle.net/bhuwanb9/fvq7u0pk/7/ ....use `margin-left` for shake animation instead of `transform`

Comment: Thanks Bhuwan, you saved my day. This is the best answer.